# PHP SESSION based shopping cart

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I'm using a `SESSION['cart']` for a shopping cart:

```
if(isset($_GET['product_id'])){

    echo 'Good request!';

    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        echo 'There is no cart!';
    }
    $cart_row = array(
        'product_id'=>$product_id
    );

    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart_row;
}
```

When I add an item using:

```
addToCart.php?product_id=12345
```

The first item is not added, but subsequent items are.

Not sure why the first item isn't making it into the array?

Comment: are calling session_start()?

Comment: Why don't you just have product ids as elements of $_SESSION['cart']?

Comment: How exactly are you checking what's in there? With `print_r($_SESSION)`?

Comment: Using Quasdunk idea to print_r shows the element is in there. Problem is Im not getting to it during iteration

Answer (score 0):

if $__GET[‘product_id’] is value (say 1, 2 or 3), then why not just do the following

```
 $_SESSION[‘cart’][]=$product_id;
 print_r($_SESSION);
```

would output:
     Array ( [cart] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) )